# How to get the value from passed variable from different function in Android

Tags: android, json, function, global-variables

```
String team;

id = array.getString("id");
init(id);
textview.setText(team);

Void init(String id_temp){
  try{
  //Calculation with the id_temp
  team = id_temp.getString("team_name");
  } catch(Exception e){}
}
```

I'm using json to get data for my app.
Here the variable id stores the ID
And in init function I'm setting the value of variable team and trying to set it to textview.

But I get null returned.
I've checked that my json is not wrong but it is fine and I added a toast in init function so it works well but the value is not returned.

Help!

Comment: put e.printStacktrace() inside catch block to get exception if occurred.

Comment: I've done there is no exception occuring

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a JSONObject of the string passed first,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(id_temp);
```

then to get the team name

```
team = jsonObject.getString("team_name");
```

Comment: My dear friend I didn't asked for json code I've written there calculation I'm successful in getting json data. This is just an example

Comment: I've failed when I'm setting textview value

Comment: If the textView is an instance variable then you can just set the text inside the init method, instead of calling it after init.

Comment: No its in a recylerview and I've no option I've to set it in the other function

Comment: provide full code then, your example itself is pathetic, passing string and treating like json. @karimelghandour provided perfect answer for **what you have asked** we dont even know whether your team variable belongs to same class or not. please put up full code in question to get better answers.

Comment: @PranavFulkari the way to debug to make sure if the TextView really uses the team variable value or not is try to edit the team variable in the init method to look like something like this: 
`team = "test";`  if when you run the TextView's text is test then the issue is in your JSON, if not then as I said, try to set the text inside the init method instead.

Comment: Json is fine and I've to set the text inside other fhntion not in init.

Comment: @PranavFulkari again please read what I said. Write `team = "test";` as a debugging method first and report back with whether or not the TextView text is set as test or not. If not then you will need to set the TextView text inside of the init method instead. I think I have answered the question over and over again.